# How to use PIN for Windows 10 in a proper way, especially when you have multiple PCs?

Tags: login, windows-10, pin

When installing Windows 10, the installation mentioned "Password is so yesterday", and suggested using PIN as a password for the machine, and said PIN is per machine, while password is for the MSN account for any PC.

But I wonder say, if I have multiple PCs, such as 2 desktops and 1 notebook at home, and 1 at work, then what is a proper way to set the PIN?  If we use the same PIN every where, it may defeat the purpose, but if we use a different PIN for each PC, then how can we remember, in my case, 4 different PINs which are just some numbers?  What is a proper way to set and use the PIN for Windows 10 machines?

Comment: PIN for workplace where you need to lock & login quickly while being in the open (assuming you have numpad to avoid shoulder surfing), picture password at home.

Comment: what do you mean "picture password at home"?  Do you mean, at home, use the MSN password instead?

Comment: No, Picture Password is another option beside PIN. It work best for tablet, but it also works with mouse. Personally I think it's better to avoid using the Live account password for PC login, for scenarios like when you need to allow someone to access your PC in emergency so you don't have to change the Live account later.

Comment: if we don't use the Live account to log in, I wonder why not let us use alphabets, such as wahnb1 which stands for "wah" + NoteBook 1 to login, but requires us to use some numbers such as 274632 which doesn't have much meanings like the alphabets (and/or possible digits).

Comment: I suppose you mean "if we don't use the live password". If you use local account you're free to use any alphabets unrelated to your live account, although of course you lose most synchronization feature (Mail, Calendar, and One Drive can still be assigned to your live account though).

Curiously, at least one pre-release version of Windows 10 allow PIN to use alphabets. For whatever reason, it's reverted to number only in later build (and RTM).